# android application only for handset, how ?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an application that should be run only in handset.

for only tablet I set this

```
<supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="false"
            android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
            android:smallScreens="false"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

But how could I do the same for only phone devices?

I read about  `<compatible-screens>`but it doesn't help me.(for example application not compatible for some phones (like HTC One, Samsung Galaxy s3,s4 and so on))

Could you tell me a best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 
    `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true">` 
to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: There is tablet that have telephony too.

Comment: Any tablet that has telephony is a just a big phone. If you want to differentiate on the ability to make calls, you can. if you want to just separate phones from tablets based on some other magical attribute, that distinction doesn't exist. It then just all comes down to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Is the manifest entry needed for phones only

Comment: Samsung Galaxy s3,s4 and HTC one belong to largeScreen and that mean it's not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) to check in android documentation.